# Update Specific Row in Database using Check Box Checked Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a web app that takes generates a barcode image based on user input.
The user chooses values that are stored in a database that are then shown on a databound checkbox. My procedure inserts the user input values in the database with no issue, but it creates new data in the database. What I'm trying to figure out is, how to determine a Where clause in a sense whether it's in my stored procedure or in my code where that the whichever databound checkbox is chosen it updates that specific row in my database as opposed of creating a new row. Mind you, it's only one checkbox as opposed to a checkbox list.

```
protected void gen_barcode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    int i = Int32.Parse(amount.Text);

    string date_picker = datepicker.Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "barcode_insert"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", amount.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", datepicker);

    if (CheckBox_Code.Checked)
    {
          //generate image code
    }

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Checkbox Bind

```
public void CheckBoxBind()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection());

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {

       cmd.CommandText = "Select CheckBoxCode FROM CodeTable Where CheckBoxCode LIKE 'EX'"
       cmd.Connection = conn;
       conn.Open();

       using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd. ExecuteReader())
       {
          while (rdr.Read()
          {
             CheckBox_Code.Text = rdr["CheckBoxCode"].ToString()
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckBoxCode", CheckBox_Code)
          }
       }

       conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 6 of your CheckBoxBind() needs to use the parameter name in the select statement:

`cmd.CommandText = "Select CheckBoxCode FROM CodeTable Where CheckBoxCode = @CheckBoxCode`"

Comment: Actually, my initial code was incorrect, it's actually supposed to be Where CheckBoxCode LIKE 'EX' so using that of course yields a declaration error. I'm going to edit my code to reflect that.